# Using smarty {assign} inside JS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I want to be able to detect mobile device using JS as frontend and better to do this way but needing to assign to a smarty assign tag is this possible?

I need to be able to define if mobile or desktop device to load the email.tpl as cannot load the form twice as breaks so need to be independant on the page otherwise would hide, well without replicating JS. If it is not possible will have to assign seperate classes and IDs to the forms but want as clean as possible and would be handy to detect with smarty as well.

Here is the current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
 * jQuery.browser.mobile (http://detectmobilebrowser.com/)
 * jQuery.browser.mobile will be true if the browser is a mobile device
 **/
(function(a) {
  (jQuery.browser = jQuery.browser || {}).mobile = /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))
})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);

alert("device detection:" + jQuery.browser.mobile);
if(jQuery.browser.mobile == true){
  // set mobile status js / smarty vars

  {assign var="is_mobile" value="true"}

  var is_mobile = "true";
} else if(jQuery.browser.mobile == false) {
  // set mobile status js / smarty vars

  {assign var="is_mobile" value="false"}

  var is_mobile = "false";
}
alert("is mobile (js):" + is_mobile);
</script>
{assign var="ajax_form" value="cm-ajax"}

{include file="views/profiles/components/profiles_scripts.tpl"}

<div style="margin-top: 100px;">is mobile: {$is_mobile}</div>
<div class="checkout-progress mobile-only">
  <ul class="row collapse">
    <li class="span4 status-bag active">
      <span class="ty-step__container-active">
        <h3 class="ty-step__title-active clearfix">
          <span class="ty-step__title-left"><i class="am-icon-shopping-basket"></i></span>
          <span class="ty-step__title-txt">{__("express_checkout")}</span>
        </h3>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li class="span4 status-delivery disabled">
      <span class="ty-step__container-active">
        <h3 class="ty-step__title-active clearfix">
          <span class="ty-step__title-left"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i></span>
          <span class="ty-step__title-txt">Delivery</span>
        </h3>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li class="span4 status-payment disabled">
      <span class="ty-step__container-active">
        <h3 class="ty-step__title-active clearfix">
          <span class="ty-step__title-left"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>
          <span class="ty-step__title-txt">{__("billing_options")}</span>
        </h3>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="cm-save-fields clearfix" id="onestepcheckout">
  <!-- MOBILE ONLY - SHOW THE EMAIL SECTION (PRE CHECKOUT) -->
  {if $is_mobile == "true"}
    {include file="addons/onestepcheckout/views/onestepcheckout/sections/email.tpl" device="mobile"}
  {/if}
  <div class="{if $addons.onestepcheckout.layout_columns == 3}span4 column-bag{else}col1{/if}">
      {include file="addons/onestepcheckout/views/onestepcheckout/sections/cart.tpl"}
      <div class="pre-checkout-summary">
        {include file="addons/onestepcheckout/views/onestepcheckout/sections/pre_summary.tpl"}
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- DESKTOP ONLY - SHOW THE EMAIL SECTION (PRE CHECKOUT) -->
  {if $is_mobile == "false"}
    {include file="addons/onestepcheckout/views/onestepcheckout/sections/email.tpl" device="desktop"}
  {/if}
  <div class="checkout-email-active span8">
    <form name="onestepcheckout_form" action="{""|fn_url}" method="post">
      <div class="{if $addons.onestepcheckout.layout_columns == 3}span6{else}col1{/if}">
          {include file="addons/onestepcheckout/views/onestepcheckout/sections/customer.tpl"}
      </div>
      <div class="{if $addons.onestepcheckout.layout_columns == 3}span6{else}col2{/if}">
          {include file="addons/onestepcheckout/views/onestepcheckout/sections/shipping.tpl"}
          {include file="addons/onestepcheckout/views/onestepcheckout/sections/payment.tpl"}
          {include file="addons/onestepcheckout/views/onestepcheckout/sections/summary.tpl"}
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
<!--onestepcheckout--></div>
{if !$auth.user_id}
    <div  id="checkout_login_block" class="hidden" title="{__("sign_in")}">
        <div class="login-popup">
            {include file="views/auth/login_form.tpl" style="popup" id="popup_checkout_login_block"}
        </div>
    </div>
{/if}
{capture name="mainbox_title"}<span class="ty-checkout__title">{__("secure_checkout")}<i class="ty-checkout__title-icon ty-icon-lock"></i></span>{/capture}
```

Comment: you can't execute php with the help of js

Comment: Thanks mate, makes sense. Was able to do slightly different by using passed variables from the include to the tpl and using that way which worked out well. Would be handy if you could do that though or they included in future releases i guess. Thanks again